# Sitecore 8 shell controller returning IIS 404

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, sitecore, sitecore8

I am currently getting IIS 8 404 error on all controller requests being made when trying to access Experience Optimization tile in sitecore 8 update 5 admin area. The partial path to controller looks something like this http://sitecore/shell/api/ct/TestOutcomes

The interesting points are all the other sitecore admin tiles are working with no problems this includes successful controller calls where required. The website is also operational. I can't see any errors/warnings in the sitecore logs or in the event viewer.

I am trying to get this working so I can do a/b testing on the pages. I know its not much to go on but I am hoping you can point me in the right direction to successfully troubleshoot this.

Comment: The path should have `/api/` in it - `sitecore/shell/api/ct/TestOutcomes`. Can you confirm you have this by using fiddler?

Comment: Maybe another route is set up that conflicts?

Comment: Apologise for the typo. Yes I can confirm it has /api/ in the path

Comment: Definetly no other routes have been set up that may conflict.

Comment: Do you have any custom processors in the initialize or HttpRequestBegin pipeline?

Comment: Yep in initialize im registering my webapi routes (do not conflict with the route above) and  to suppressXFrameoptions AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true

Comment: In httpBeignRequest I have added class to deal with sitecore item not found errors to transfer to custom 404 and <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel">
          <patch:delete />
        </processor>

Comment: Already tried removing all these and try again but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was via xml transformation I was removing few tags in`App_Config\Include\ContentTesting\Sitecore.ContentTesting.config`
to make sitecore instance quicker (only in dev).

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterContentTestingCommandRoute, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
    <processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.Initialize.PrecompileSpeakViews, Sitecore.Speak.Client" use="ContentTesting">
        <Paths>/sitecore/shell/client/Applications/ContentTesting</Paths>
    </processor>
</initialize>
```

What I failed to notice that I should not remove this live as it registers the routes

```
<processor type="Sitecore.ContentTesting.Pipelines.Initialize.RegisterContentTestingCommandRoute, Sitecore.ContentTesting" patch:before="processor[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes, Sitecore.Mvc']" />
```

After placing this back in the config everything works.